# ¿Cómo escribo una función con este ejemplo en R?

Tags: r, funciones, bucles

Tengo el siguiente `data.frame`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es el 2% de la población, que tenga el valor más alto en cada una de las variables (`VGleche`, `VGkg`, `VGkp`). Hasta ahora he hecho algo demasiado básico y nada ágil para salir del paso, y resolver lo que necesito, pero creo que debe haber alguna manera más eficiente de hacerlo, sin tener que repetir una y otra vez las siguientes líneas de comando para cada variable

```
top2<-arrange(df, VGleche) #Primero ordeno de mayor a menor mi variable
top3<-top2[1:580,]         #Luego me quedo con el 2% del total de los datos... 
                            Sé que son 580 porque lo he calculado a mano
range(top3$VGleche)        #Esto lo hago porque me interesa saber el rango de 
                            ese 2%
```

¿Hacer una función ayudaría? Aunque mi conocimiento se limita a funciones extremadamente básicas. ¿Cómo podría agilizar lo que busco? En realidad tengo 20 variables y he tenido que repetir 60 veces esas 3 lineas de comando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementando un poco la solución de JRN

```
set.seed(2019)
#Funcion que calcula una función sobre p% más alto o más bajo del vector a
ordenar2_function = function(a,p=0.02,decreasing=FALSE,fun=range) {
  #a: es el vector de datos
  #p: esta dado en proporcion, es decir si deseo calcular  una función al 50%
  #más alto defino p=0.5
  #decreasing: FALSE para p% más alto. TRUE para p% más bajo.
  #fun: función para aplicar sobre a, por defecto range.
  fun(sort(a, decreasing=decreasing)[1:ceiling((length(a)*p))])
  #sort ordena a
  #[1:ceiling((length(a)*p))] toma el p% más alto de a ordenado
  #length(a) calcula la longitud de df p.e. 100 al multiplicar por p obtenemos el p%
  #ceiling() toma el entero mayor inmediato de un número decimal
}


df<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000,1000,100),100,10)) #DF ALEATORIO 

#Usamos apply para recorrer las variables y aplicar ordenar2_funcion
apply(df[,2:10], #podemos seleccionar las variables de interes p.e. de la 2 a la 10
           2, function(x){ #El dos indica que se aplicara la función 
             #sobre las columnas de df, puede ser 1 para aplicar sobre las filas.
             ordenar2_function(a=x,fun=mean) #Aplicado la media
           })

#Ejemplo aplicando la función range
apply(df[5:8], 2, function(x){ordenar2_function(a=x,fun=range)})
```

Salida. Para cada variable tenemos el mínimo en la primera fila y el maximo en la segunda.

```
           V5       V6       V7       V8
[1,] 730.0383 794.0298 769.6017 681.3682
[2,] 776.2846 825.6638 786.8856 730.6376
```

Entonces ahora puedes sustituir `fun` por otras funciones p.e. `var` para calcular varianza  o `summary` que devuelve (min, q1, median, mean, q3, max).

Comment: excelente! Era lo que buscaba! Muchas gracias. Sólo una pregunta (por desconocimiento mío sobre hacer funciones en R) ¿Qué hace exactamente esta parte de la función[1:ceiling((length(a)*p))]? y con function(a,p=0.02), la p=0.02 indica directamente en la función "porcentaje"?

Comment: y otra pregunta, apply(df[,2:10], 
2, ordenar2) --> ese 2 que está antes de la coma de ordenar2, qué indica?

Comment: Y otras 2 preguntas... 1)Que debería hacer para conocer la media de ese 2% de los datos? He intentado varias cosas pero no lo consigo... y 2)Cómo genero un listado aparte de ese 2%? Ahora me doy cuenta que necesito saber quienes son exactamente esos individuos. Gracias!

Comment: Ok.. perdón deje muy a la interpretación. Antes que nada mencionar que siempre puedes consultar la documentación de una función en R usando `?nombre_de_la_función`

Comment: @Caro he editado la respuesta para que la función ahora ordenar2_function puede aplicar esa cualquier función. P.e. para que te regrese los valores ordenados sin modificaros puedes hacer `function(x){x}` pero toma en cuenta que en cada variable los individuos con los valores mayores pueden ser diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

```
ordenar2 = function(a) {
sort(a, decreasing=FALSE)[1:ceiling((length(a)*0.02))]
}

ordenar2(a)
```

entonces solo debes usar la funcion y te dará el 2% de los valores mas altos.

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una opción integramente `dplyr`:

```
# a modo de ejemplo, generamos un df de 100 filas y 5 columnas
set.seed(2019)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000,1000,100),100,5))

df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(V1:V5), funs(sort)) %>% 
    top_n(nrow(.)*.02)

        V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
1 1237.545 1199.863 1216.064 1200.844 1280.682
2 1263.602 1219.575 1230.190 1207.000 1326.278
```

Detalle:

- Con `mutate_at()` aplicamos a las columnas `V1` a la `V5` (`vars(V1:V5)`) la función `sort` (`funs(sort)`)
- Luego simplemente nos quedamos con las `top_n()` observaciones dónde `n` sería el 2% (`nrow(.)*.02`)

Nota: incluso es más simple en el caso que quieras aplicar el `sort` sobre todas las columnas:

```
df %>% 
    mutate_all(sort) %>% 
    top_n(nrow(.)*.02)
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, muy útil y sencilla tu sugerencia también. Lo único que hecho en falta es la partecita de ver el rango de valores de ese 2%.